# EasyCap USB 2.0 produces BSOD in Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, bsod

I recently got an EasyCap Video Adapter, which I want to use to upload old VHS tapes to my PC and burn them to DVDs. I installed the appropiate drivers and the Ulead Video Studio software that comes with it. When I open the video software, a dialog box comes up with a progress bar and starts to do something (not sure what, the message isn't too descriptive). When it ends, I click accept and get an instant BSOD. I tried doing the same through VLC, going to Media -> Open Capture Device, and selecting the devices. I press Play on the VCR and when I press Play in VLC, I get the BSOD again.

Anyone have a similar experience? I'm going to try doing this with Windows XP.

Comment: Did you get it to work?

Comment: @Synetech: After reinstalling Windows for unrelated reasons, it now works. I still have a couple of issues, but I think those happen in Windows XP too.

Comment: Okay thanks. I’m looking at these on eBay, so it’s good to have a bit of feedback.